# Convert NSPoint in screen coordinates to window coordinates

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop

I am implementing drag and drop in a cocoa application and I am using the following method from the NSDraggingSource Protocol:

```
- (void)draggedImage:(NSImage *)draggedImage movedTo:(NSPoint)screenPoint{
```

The NSPoint is given in screen coordinates and I need it in window or view coordinates. If the method was called with an NSEvent I could do the following:

```
    -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)pTheEvent {

 NSPoint tvarMouseInWindow = [pTheEvent locationInWindow];
 NSPoint tvarMouseInView   = [self convertPoint:tvarMouseInWindow fromView:nil]; }
```

But I cannot figure out how to do it with just an NSPoint. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at the NSWindow documentation, there is a

```
- (NSPoint)convertScreenToBase:(NSPoint)aPoint
```

which will let you convert the point to window coordinates.

Comment: `(NSPoint)convertScreenToBase:(NSPoint)aPoint` is now deprecated in favor of `(NSRect)convertRectFromScreen:(NSRect)aRect`. Obviously one can convert a point to a rectangle, use this method, and then convert back, but is this really the preferred idiom now? There's got to be a better way.

Comment: @Omphalos: there doesn't seem to be a better way (or I'm completely missing it), so I wound up writing a new method on a category of NSWindow that builds an NSRect, converts it, and returns the origin of the converted rect. It kind of restores the behavior of `-convertScreenToBase:`, and gives you an opportunity to name it more in line with other similar methods; I called mine `-convertPointFromScreen:`.